# php - Datastore: TextProperty (is there such a thing?)

Tags: php, google-cloud-datastore

I need to store a long text/string in google Datastore. This text is a serialized associative array which is 6.40 KB(more than 500 characters).
I'm using Google AppEngine: PHP and google-api-php-client library.

What I've done so far is using these ways:

- stringValue
- stringValue + indexed = false;
- blobValue
- blobValue + indexed = false;
- blobValue + blobKeyValue

But I don't get any result in lookup(). When I leave the indexed property as default, I don't get any peroperty in the result set, and when I set it to false(unindexed), I just get indexed property back and no other value. When I also check the Developers Console, it shows Unknown for the property value type.

There is something similar to what I need in Python developer's guide:"

> class TextProperty()
> A long string.
>
> Unlike StringProperty, a TextProperty value can be more than 500 characters long. However, TextProperty values are not indexed and cannot be used in filters or sort orders.

Any idea? please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `stringValue` for both indexed and unindexed string values, but indexed values must be <= 500 characters.

To insert a string property longer than 500 characters, you must explicitly set `indexed` to `false`, otherwise Cloud Datastore will not accept the entity.

https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#Datastore_Properties_and_value_types

Comment: Honestly, I don't know how I missed this one, because I tried everything as you might recognized in my description above. My brain might be so tired at that time. Thank you anyway.